# scroll to bottom of heightless dynamic div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a div that contains some log

```
<div id="log">
   <div class="logitem"></div>
   <div class="logitem"></div>
   <div id="containerbottom"></div> 
</div>
```

To the log , on runtime, Im appending more unknown number of `<div class="logitem"></div>`.

I want to scroll to the bottom of the container right after appending the item

I have tried using :

```
$('#log').animate({
     scrollTop: $('#containerbottom').offset().top
});
```

but it doesnt seem to perform well.

what are my other options to do that ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a function that is called at an interval to scroll down:

```
function scrollDown()
{
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() },'slow');
}

setInterval(scrollDown,1000); // Executes function every 1,000 milliseconds.
```

**Edit:**

I've recently discovered it's a good practice to use a recursive `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` when possible to avoid clogging the event queue and causing tons of repeating error messages if there's an error. This method is only suited for applications that don't need precise timing. If you still need your function called *exactly* every 1,000 milliseconds (e.g. a stopwatch) then continue using `setInterval`.

Example:

```
(function scrollDown(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() },'slow');
    setTimeout(scrollDown,1000);
})();
```

If your jQuery animations are piling up on jQuery's animation queue, you might want to use `.stop().animate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to animate #log, when it's actually html & body (I use both, to fix some browsers that don't like one or the other).

Here's a quick little function I use in my JS library, dynamic to just except any #id, but basically it scrolls $('html, body').animate();

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NEYye/)

```
jNamespace._goToByScroll = function(id) {
    //NOTE: Scroll to specific #ID in html
    //Useage: jNamespace.goToByScroll('top') - ommit #, added inside function
    //ENDNOTE

    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top }, 'slow');
};
```